# Get Unique Count of Names In Excel Column Excluding Certain Text Or Empty Cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to get a unique count for a column of names. Some cells may be blank or have "Cancelled" in them. How do I get a count of unique text and exclude empty cells or those with "Cancelled" in them?

This is what I have so far - it appears to get the unique count, but fails with empty cell and includes "Cancelled": `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(G2:G29,G2:G29,0),MATCH(G2:G29,G2:G29,0))>0,1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the condition to the IF:

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IFERROR(MATCH(G2:G29,G2:G29,0),FALSE)*(LEN(G2:G29)>0)*(G2:G29<>"Cancelled"),IF((LEN(G2:G29)>0)*(G2:G29<>"Cancelled"),IFERROR(MATCH(G2:G29,G2:G29,0),FALSE)))>0))
```

Remember this is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of Enter.

[image]

Comment: If doing just enter, it gives the same number (which looks to be correct - will accept this answer when I can). What's the difference?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: 2016 - also empty cells seem to fail

Comment: Weird - still erroring out with empty cells. That's ok - you did what I needed. I can work around the rest. Thank you!